# Bamboo build with local and remote agents

Tags: msbuild, specflow, bamboo

I have a .Net WebApi project and continuous integration is setup using Bamboo. I am using spec flow tests and some of the tests are tagged to run on bamboo remote agent as they are slow in nature. Other tests supposed to be run on multiple local agents. I have setup multiple stages in Bamboo build plan as stages get run in parallel with each stage is set to run specifically tagged tests suits.

My question is what is the general practice to setup a Bamboo plan to run on multiple agents (local and remote) and how can I share one MS Build output (dlls and config) across multiple agents.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to split build and test phase then usually you have Build stage with one job which produces artifact with build output.

Then you create another stage and put several jobs there. Jobs may be configured to download produced artifact from Build stage and execute tests against your build.

If you want to run some of your jobs at remote agent, you can add some Job requirement which only remote agent can satisfy.

Comment: Thanks. Procucing artifacts and uding them to another stages makes sense. Will I be able to share associated config files with artifacts too? My artifacts (DLLs) will require associated config files to run them by later stages. Also, I assume that I'll be able to use shared artifacts in remote agent as artifacts will be produced by local agent and needs to be used by remote agent.

Comment: Sure, artifacts are generated by pattern like "**/*.dll" - all dll files from all folders, or "**/*.*" to copy all files from all folders